# Bitbake recipe is failing to chown various files and directories

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm making a customized poky setup, which seems to be giving me some issues. I've refactored poky from branch "dunfell", and added a few layers. Initially, I moved all of the layers, including the layers in the base poky directory to a new directory, "layers". I've refactored bblayers.conf to point to this new location, and attempted to build core-image-minimal. No luck. Continuously got some error where a recipe within db-native (meta/recipes-support/db/db_5.3.28.bb) fails in do_install() where chown -R root:root ... is called.

After some messing around to no avail, I decide to remove all extra layers, as well as my own custom layer to isolate the problem. I'm now down to bblayers.conf only pointing to meta, meta-yocto-bsp, and meta-poky all within my new layers dir (poky/layers/meta*). Everything that I'm aware of that needs to be refactored to see this new layers dir has (as far as I know) been taken care of. Everything that I refactored was oe-init-build-env, .templateconf, and bblayers.conf.sample.

Now with only these three layers, and everything refactored, I try to build core-image-minimal again, to no avail. I get the same exact error, abridged here:

```
oc/articles/inmemory': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/doc/articles': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/doc': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/recipe-sysroot-native': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build/tmp': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test/build': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]/test': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/[redacted]': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image/space': Operation not permitted
| chown: changing ownership of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image': Operation not permitted
| WARNING: [redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/temp/run.do_install.6001:1 exit 1 from 'chown -R root:root [redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/image'
| ERROR: Execution of '[redacted]/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/db-native/1_5.3.28-r1/temp/run.do_install.6001' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:[redacted]/test/layers/meta/recipes-support/db/db_5.3.28.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 392 tasks of which 370 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:[redacted]/test/layers/meta/recipes-support/db/db_5.3.28.bb:do_install
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

As some background, my forked poky is setup as such:

```
./
.git/
.repo/
bitbake/
build/
contrib/
documentation/
scripts/
layers/
meta-skeleton/
oe-init-build-env*
.gitignore
.templateconf
MEMORIAM
```

and here is the layers dir:

```
./
meta-openembedded/
meta-poky/
meta-qt5/
meta-raspberrypi/
meta-rpi/
meta-yocto-bsp/
meta/
```

bblayers.conf is as such:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  [redacted]/test/layers/meta \
  [redacted]/test/layers/meta-poky \
  [redacted]/test/layers/meta-yocto-bsp \
```

I've found a lot of similar issues scouring the web, although many seem to be different in such a way that it's not applicable (e.g. network related, different recipe, etc.). A couple extremely similar questions I've found relating directly to this were never answered.

I definitely appreciate the help from anyone willing! Thanks!

Comment: " I've refactored poky from branch "dunfell"" --> What did you change?

Comment: Strictly naming schemes and file organization to fit a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the scripts/native-intercept directory is empty?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."